# Alternative to runUntilDate for waiting until animation is complete

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c-blocks

We have an application that has some code similar to the following:

```
[UIView animationWithDuration: 0.7f animations {
   // Some animations
}];
[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate: [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 0.7f]];
```

To wait for an animation block to complete and continue executing code as if the animation block were essentially synchronous.  This has worked in all past versions of iOS, but does not seem to be working properly on iPhone 12 devices running iOS 15.

Is there an alternative to this approach to waiting for an animation to complete using semaphores, dispatch barriers, or something similar?  We tried moving the code that should run after the animation into the animation completion block, but it is difficult to do so because the logic is complex and there are several levels of nested conditionals.  Ideally, we would like to find something that works in a similar manner to runUntilDate by yielding the main thread for a specific period of time without blocking it and then continuing execution once the asynchronous animation is completed.

Comment: I would advise against this pattern entirely. These `UIView` block-based animations come with a completion handler rendition and you should put your steps dependent upon the finishing of the animation in these completion blocks.

Comment: I agree that refactoring using completion handlers would be the optimal approach and we went down that path initially.  However, this is a legacy codebase with a complicated logic flow and we have found several portions of code where the completion handler based approach doesn't work well.  For example, we have a while loop that triggers a series of animations which chain perfectly using the runUntilDate approach, but this would need to be completely refactored to use completion handlers.  I would love to find a direct replacement or workaround for the runUntilDate approach if possible.

Comment: Yeah, but sadly refactoring really is the right solution.

Comment: By the way, you say that it “does not seem to be working properly”. Perhaps you can describe in what way it is no longer working (e.g. describe what it does on other versions of the device/OS and what you’re experiencing). You should edit question to include a [minimal, yet reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Comment: Just wanted to provide a quick follow-up on this.  We investigated a wide variety of workarounds, but were not able to find anything that replicates runUntilDate's functionality of yielding code execution for a specific time while animations run on iOS 15 on iPhone 12 + 13.  We ended up refactoring the application to use asynchronous completion blocks, as suggested by Rob, rather than runUntilDate and it is working properly again.